# Marketing Cloud query activity using dateadd()

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am currently constructing a query that will add people into a data extension when their event_date is 28, 21, 14 or 7 days away. I currently use

```
WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False'
AND [Event_StartDate] >= DateAdd(day,28,cast(GetDate() as date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DateAdd(day,29,cast(GetDate() as date))
```

to get those 28 days away, but how would I write the rest of it to add those people 21 or 14 days away? I'm not sure whereabouts the 'ORs' and 'ANDs' need to go. I have tried

```
WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False'
AND [Event_StartDate] >= DateAdd(day,28,cast(GetDate() as date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DateAdd(day,29,cast(GetDate() as date))
OR WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False'
AND [Event_StartDate] >= DateAdd(day,21,cast(GetDate() as date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DateAdd(day,22,cast(GetDate() as date))
OR WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False'
AND [Event_StartDate] >= DateAdd(day,14,cast(GetDate() as date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DateAdd(day,15,cast(GetDate() as date))
```

But that doesn't transfer any records. Clearly my syntax is wrong somewhere.

Comment: why you're not using Data Filter?

Comment: It's being used in an automation daily to be added to a journey.

Comment: Also it only copies a few fields, not the whole data extension.

Comment: WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False'
AND (
([Event_StartDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 28, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DATEADD(DAY, 29, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
OR ([Event_StartDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 21, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DATEADD(DAY, 22, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
OR ([Event_StartDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 14, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DATEADD(DAY, 15, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
)

Comment: hope this may work.

Answer (score 3):

Patash's solution in the comments section is correct.  The issue with TCassa's original query was that is required parenthesis around the **OR** conditions.

An alternative solution would be to use [DateDiff()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/datediff/) function, rather than [DateAdd()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/dateadd/).  This makes it a bit easier to check for additional dates in the query without using **OR** statements.

```
WHERE hasMadeApplication = 'False' 
AND DateDiff(Day,getDate(),[Event_StartDate]) 
in (28, 21, 14 , 7 )
```